# Windows commands not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Any one knows why these Windows commands are not working??
The basic commands are also not working.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "c:\windows\system32\" in environment variable.

To add this Mycomputer right click properties> Advanced>Environment variables

In that you can see `System variables`. In that you can see on variable with name `PATH`.
If it already contain some values add `;` and then add `"C:\WINDOWS\system32"` (without quotes). if `PATH` not
contain any values add just `"C:\WINDOWS\system32"` (without quotes)

Comment: It's funny Dhanish when I asked you in an earlier thread if you'd changed PATH and you ignored me.  You seem to know the thank-you word but you're very careful who you give it to.

Comment: @foxidrive, you would have tell me what is PATH and how to check and change it; as I'm new to this i couldn't understand your comment

Answer (score 1):

You have probably changed your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: How to change it back ?

Comment: the PATH is printed as `PATH=E:\Program files\Java\jre\bin;E:\Program files\ant\bin`. Is this correct? If not how can i change it? Windows is installed on C: and the JRE is installed on E:

Comment: Easiest way is to start a new `cmd` session and read the path from there - provided it hasn't been damaged in the registry. If it has been damaged, you'll need to re-set it in the registry, otherwise you are likely to lose access to many installed programs.